# How to execute a python script in access by VBA?

Tags: python, vba, ms-access

Below is the code snippet:

```
Private Sub Toggle10_Click()
    Call Shell("python.exe D:\project\nc\test.py ", 1)
End Sub
```

But it is failing to print the result. How can I execute a python script in access by VBA?

Comment: Is it really failing to print, or is the window in which it runs disappearing before you get the chance to read it? Put your invocation of Python in a batch file and put `pause` in the next line, then run the batch file from VBA. What happens then?

Comment: it runs disappearing before you get the chance to read it

Comment: Then use the batch file approach that I suggested, or get your Python program to wait for a keystroke before terminating.

Comment: Thanks  I'll try

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem which arises when executing Office Automation processes from within MS Office Applications like Excel, Access, Word and so on.  When Office application VBA invokes a Shell command, like that above, it's really asking the Windows OS to perform a system call to the target resource, in this case a specific Python executable.  Left to its on devices, the Office App will continue to execute and the Python code executes in parallel…Office has not waited for the return from Python and those two processes never really connect.

MS Access is particularly vulnerable to this situation.  To fix this problem it is necessary to halt the execution of MS Access in order to allow Python to complete its task and return a result.  There are three ways to do this:

Intrinsic Wait function in Excel. – does not work in MS Access

Windows (system) Sleep function. – Sleep ####, where #### is a number of milliseconds: Sleep 1000

Windows (system) GetTickCount function. - Pause asynchronously via WaitAsync (####, milliseconds)

For MS Access the easiest by far to use is the intrinsic Sleep function.   WaitAsync is a standard public function and can be found on the web easily.